# Strategy for managing long GUI construction times (wxPython)

Tags: python, matplotlib, wxpython, wxwidgets

I have a wxPython application with a multi-stage GUI.  First a simple form pops for selecting from one of many (> 100) options (it's a part number list with a search box).  Once the user has made their selection it builds the appropriate form and shows it, hiding the initial selection dialog.  Due to the nature of this project, each secondary form has several matplotlib figures in a `Notebook`, around 7 or 8 figures each with 2-5 axes each.  Because of this, the form takes several seconds between initialization and when it can be shown on the screen.

Does wxPython have a way to build a frame in the background?  I don't mind forcing the user to wait a short while before it can be shown, but as it is right now building the form hogs the event loop and everything becomes unresponsive.  If I use a thread to build the form, it completes successfully but when I call `.Show()` nothing happens and there's no error message.

As you can imagine, such a GUI has fairly complex code so it would be difficult to show a [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org/) (and it's not open source).  If needed I can try to hack together something that would approximate my problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have used BusyInfo before to tell the user that something is happening. You would put that in your frame's **init**() BEFORE you actually start creating the matplotlib figures. You can read about it here:

- http://wiki.wxpython.org/BusyInfo

Another idea would be to create a second frame with a progressbar in it and a message. The progressbar would be set to just bounce back and forth and when you got done creating the matplot stuff, you would close the second frame.

Comment: The `BusyInfo` is an acceptable solution to this problem, I can just put a generic loading message and it gives clear indication to the user that something is happening with minimal effort.

Answer (score 0):

Mike's idea of using `wxBusyInfo` is useful when something takes a long time, but it's possible you could make it take less time instead (or at least as well).

First, when inserting many (although I wouldn't say that 100 is that many, 1000 however definitely is) items into a `wxChoice`, [freeze](http://docs.wxwidgets.org/trunk/classwx_window.html#a15c678314cfc1d807196bc298b713ed3) it before adding them -- and [thaw](http://docs.wxwidgets.org/trunk/classwx_window.html#a279a532124073261b28131b6afb59a1e) it afterwards. This should cut down the time needed for the insertion drastically.

Second, creating all controls of a multi-page `wxNotebook` (or another `wxBookCtrl`) can be long, even in C++. So the idea is to not do it immediately but only create the controls of the page you are going to initially show to the user. And then create the other pages controls only when the user is about to select them, i.e. in your `wxEVT_BOOKCTRL_PAGE_CHANGING` event handler.

If you put this in place, you might not need `wxBusyInfo` any longer...

Comment: I've considered only building the pages when they're viewed, but the problem is also that I need to graph data on the matplotlib plots on all tabs of the notebook simultaneously and certainly before the user clicks on that page.